Is there a way to move package used in an old project to a new project in flutter offline?
I'll be a flutter teacher teaching students in village and the internet there is soooo sloooow, so I thought that is there a way to move the package instead of download it.
I have search everywhere, but I didn't find anyone taking about it...
